# how post and get specialchars in url?

Tags: php, url, get

how post and get "&" symbol in url? in php. please help me ........

Comment: You'll need to explain your question in more detail ...

Comment: if u print $_GET['searchword'] , what u get ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107401/how-post-and-get-specialchars-in-url

Answer (score 4):

Encode data with [urlencode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php). It will be decoded automatically when parsed into $_POST.

Answer (score 2):

use `urldecode`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

```
$searchword = urldecode($_GET['searchword']);
```

Comment: output: "G".
how get all values?

Comment: if u print $_GET['searchword'] , what u get ?

Comment: if i print this
echo $searchword = urldecode('G+%26+G+Tours');

i get : "G & G Tours"

Answer (score 0):

encoded as "%26".

u can use function `urlencode()`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
index.php?searchword=G%20%26%20G%20Tours
```

Comment: `+` in a query string is equivalent to `%20` according to the specs.

Comment: form action="get" - url passing value is G+%26+G+Tours.
how i get full value?